# SQL Remove everything after certain varchar value or word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I found how to remove after certain character, but how can I remove after certain word in SQL DEV 2012?

Say I have a table called MyTable and this Column is MyTextColumn which contains

My Name is Peter the Developer this part needs to be removed.

So when it finds 'Peter the Developer' remove Peter the Developer and the rest of it that follows and the only thing that remains is 'My Name is'

Thanks

```
 UPDATE MyTable
 SET MyText = LEFT(MyText, CHARINDEX(';', MyText) - 1)
 WHERE CHARINDEX(';', MyText) > 0
```

Update:

Since my question was to remove meaning update here is what I created from responses below to make it work.

```
update myTable
set myTextColumn = SUBSTRING(myTextColumn , 0 , CHARINDEX('Peter the developer', myTextColumn, 0))
where ID = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what is the expected result

If you expect to remove everything and just keep "My Name is", you can do as below

```
declare @Word varchar(100)='My Name is Peter the Developer this part needs to be removed'
declare @Match varchar(100)='Peter the Developer'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Word , 0 , CHARINDEX(@Match, @Word, 0))
```

If you need keep "My Name is Peter the Developer"

```
declare @Word varchar(100)='My Name is Peter the Developer this part needs to be removed'
declare @Match varchar(100)='Peter the Developer'
declare @len int 

set @len = LEN(@Match)

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Word , 0 , CHARINDEX(@Match, @Word, 0)+@len)
```

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
declare @Seed nvarchar(32) =  'is '
declare @String nvarchar(128) = 'My Name is Peter'

select Left(@String,PATINDEX('%'+@Seed+'%',@String)+len(@seed))
```

Your case'

```
declare @Seed nvarchar(32) =  ';'

UPDATE MyTable
 SET MyText = Left(MyText,PATINDEX('%'+@Seed+'%',MyText)+len(@seed))
 WHERE PATINDEX('%'+@Seed+'%',MyText) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @text varchar(max) = 'My name is peter'   

UPDATE MyTable
SET MyText = SUBSTRING(@text,0,CHARINDEX('peter',@text,0))
```

Something like this should help

the output will be

**My name is**

Comment: Great response similar to the one huMpty left just before you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use charindex to look for more than one character, so:

```
select left(MyTextColumn,charindex('Peter the Developer',MyTextColumn,1)-1
from 
MyTable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5adaa/2)

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, it was very helpful but someone beat you to the punch.